# Can i get complete configuration.json file of azure-devops-migration-tools for migrating board,pipeline,repo etc

Tags: azure-devops-migration-tools

Can i get complete configuration.json file of azure-devops-migration-tools for migrating board,pipeline,repo etc
I am struggling to understand and prepare the config file can someone help me with a example or complete file.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Also this is in the documentation of the product. Please check that first and then ask a specific question.

Answer (score 0):

You can output a config with all the trimings using:

`migration.exe init --options Full`

https://github.com/nkdAgility/azure-devops-migration-tools/blob/master/docs/configuration.md